# Posting comment with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, comments

I want to display the posted comment once the user comments. Just to add it under all of them as facebook does.

I have this:

```
 // Interceptamos el evento submit
    $('#CommentAddForm').submit(function() {
        alert("entro");
        alert($(this).attr('action'));

        // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            // Mostramos un mensaje con la respuesta de PHP
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(//????????????);
            }
        });        
        return false;
    });
```

But i don't know very well how it works and i dont know what should i write in the line                     `$('#result').html(//????????????);`

The variable URL contains the route which inserts the comment in the DB. And it works well. 
Any idea? Thanks.

By the way, i have been reading this answer:
[Ajax/jQuery Comment System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129955/ajax-jquery-comment-system)
But i still don't get it.

Comment: if the data is comment you can use .append method. ı am trying it now if ı success ı will post it.

Comment: Do you have access to the POST action? Can you return the value you sent to it? Otherwise you could store it in a global JS variable before you send it.

Comment: ok. ı finished it. ı used append for that. it works fine but you can improve it with css and something like that.

Comment: Yeah, finally i got the information with jQuery, i added it to the html var and i did this $('#comments').prepend(html);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ı finished it and its work fine. when you submit, its appending your comment to commentbox as facebook does.

change your code like this:

```
var comment=$('.comment').val(); // your comment text box
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            // Mostramos un mensaje con la respuesta de PHP
            success: function(data) {

            $('.commentbox').append("</br>"+comment); // list of comments. its inserting your last comment at the end of line.

           }
        });
```